# How would i be able to copy (by Ctrl + C or Mouse right click copy option) select control option in drop down

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this drop down list

```js
function copyThis(text) {
  window.prompt("Copy this : ", text);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <select class="wrap" onchange="copyThis(this.value)">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Currently using the above it does not let me highlight or select the option that is chosen in the list. Is there a better way by double clicking and highlight the selected option so that i can Ctrl + C or Mouse right click and copy

Comment: How about a solution like: A button next to the dropdown and when you hit that button the selected option gets copied into clipboard?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1534704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a "copy" button:

```js
function copyThis(text) {
  window.prompt("Copy this : ", text);
};

$("#copy").click(function () {
  window.prompt("copy this:", $("#cars option:selected").text());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <select id="cars" class="wrap">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <button id="copy">copy</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer works but adding a button is not really an option for me, Thanks for the reply